# How to overwrite bootstrap navigation bar's collapse in CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navigation, navbar

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <!-- boostrap imports -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- navigation menu bar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- bootstrap imports -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Hello, I have tried changing the bootstrap class' features in a CSS file, but nothing I tried gave me the result I wanted (i.e. right side of the picture below). I am unsure as to which class I should be modifying. Could somebody help me please?

Note: The picture comparison I provided above is from a mobile point of view AFTER pressing the collapse button.

Comment: Do you really want the nav links outside the background of the navbar as shown in the image?

Comment: @Zim I would put the Link Link Link inside the navbar, but that sounds too difficult

Comment: @user498021: Please see my code examples here below. It gives you 2 options to solve it, also taking into account the comments here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Bootstrap class `justify-content-center` on the form, it will do what you are asking for in the right picture. And the links will be on the navbar background.

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 justify-content-center">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
</form>
```

If you want the links to be inline with the navbar, add the classes `mt-n5` and `pt-2`.

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 justify-content-center mt-n5 pt-2">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
</form>
```

Comment: @user498021: No problem and you're welcome. I realized that in order for my last example to work for widths below 576px, you just use the default classes mt-n5 and pt-2, leaving out the 'sm' modifier.